# How to replace a specific character in every element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list in Python which contains the number of posted tweets per user profile.

For example:

```
list = ['142', '1567', '153K', '32', '10', '50']
```

As you can see, when the number is very high (i.e., `153567`) instead of the actual number, `153K` is stored.

What is the simplest way of replacing the `K` character in every element of the list -- if it exists -- with `000`?

Comment: and what about "M", or "B"?...

Comment: There is something really badly defined here in that 142 is a number but 153K is not a number so it needs to be in quotes. Do you want to redefine as:     '153K' ?

Answer (score 3):

```
f = lambda x: x.replace("K", "000")
data = ["142", "1567", "153K", "32", "10", "50"]
print(list(map(f, data)))
```

**In your code, 153K is not a valid literal for any type**

**I Interprete this list as string list.**

Comment: My code is simple, but yours is more elegant. I prefer lambda's even if less readable. My code above is more for beginners so I've +1'd yours.

Answer (score 3):

Using replace function

```
[i.replace('K', '000') for i in list]
```

Then you can convert it to list o integer using int

```
[int(i.replace('K', '000')) for i in list]
```

In this case this list will return :

```
[142, 1567, 153000, 32, 10, 50]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `list comprehension` with `replace`. A single liner code :

```
[ele.replace('K','000') for ele in l]       #l is the list
```

So we get

```
IN : l = ['142', '1567', '153K', '32', '10', '50']
OUT : ['142', '1567', '153000', '32', '10', '50']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [142, 1567, '153K', 32, 10, 50]

comp_list = [x.replace('K', '000') if type(x) is str else x for x in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> list = ['142', '1567', '153K', '32', '10', '50']
>> listNoK = [item.replace('K','000') for item in list]
>> listNoK

['142', '1567', '153000', '32', '10', '50']
```

Or to get numbers:

```
>>> listNoK = [int(item.replace('K','000')) for item in list]
>>> listNoK
[142, 1567, 153000, 32, 10, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this task would be the following:

```
list = ['142', '1567', '153K', '32', '10', '50']

for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if 'K' in item:
        list[index] = item.replace('K', '000')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["142", "1567", "153K", "32", "10", "50"]
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].replace('K','000')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['142', '1567', '153000', '32', '10', '50']
```